# My server isn't be loaded after many codes

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I made a server with node js, and my localhost:4000 worked well before. And then, I wrote many codes after it. But my localhost:4000 doesn't work now. Please let me know what's wrong with it.

**app.js**:

```
import express from "express";
import morgan from "morgan";
import helmet from "helmet";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import userRouter from "./routers/userRouter";
import videoRouter from "./routers/videoRouter";
import globalRouter from "./routers/globalRouter";
import routes from "./routes";

const app = express();

const PORT = 4000;

function handleListening() {
  console.log(`listening http://localhost:${PORT}`);
}

app.listen(PORT, handleListening);

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(morgan("dev"));

app.use("routes", globalRouter);
app.use("routes.users", userRouter);
app.use("routes.videos", videoRouter);

export default app;
```

**init.js**:

```
import app from "./app";

const PORT = 4000;

const handleListening = () =>
  console.log(`Listening on: http://localhost:${PORT}`);

app.listen(PORT, handleListening);
```

Comment: Can you please check the `main` field in package.json file? I think the `main` field might be pointing to `index.js` file instead of `init.js`

Comment: What error do you get? Why are you starting the server 2 times?

Comment: App will crash if you try to start the server twice on the same port.

Answer (score 0):

Only one process can be bound to a port at a time. You are trying to start your sever twice at port 4000. You should be getting an error saying this.

If you want `init.js` to handle starting the server, remove

```
app.listen(PORT, handleListening);
```

from `app.js` and you should be good.

Comment: Your comment is in no way helpful. If you are still having problems, explain them. Update your question's code with any changes you have made and add any errors you are seeing.